# Add an image to a product description in 1.8.1

Tags: magento-1.8, attributes, template, product-images, product-view

I wish to add a "Certified Organic" logo to the Product Description of some products but not all. If I try to add an image tag to the description it does not stick. Is there another way of doing this by maybe creating an attribute that is turned on/off per product. If on the image is shown on the product page, and if off the image is not shown?

Comment: You've answered yourself, add a yes/no attribute which you can place logic on the frontend(like Matheus points out correctly)

Answer (score 1):

You need to check what type of product (simple, configurable, etc.), if the filter type, you can make a module with the only action of adding the image in the description. The file should be changed in your folder template/modulo_custom is the `app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\product\view\description.phtml`. Copy the file, change and enter the code:
`<img src = "link.of.image.jpeg" alt = "some description" />`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way:

Create an `attribute` named `organic` and make sure you set it as `Media Image` and apply this attribute to all of your `Attribute Sets`.

Now, go to your desired product's image section and upload the image and set this image to newly created attribute (`organic`) and also `exclude` it if you don't want to show in more image section.

Then, open your `template/catalog/view/description.phtml` and add following code:

```
<?php if($this->getProduct()->getOrganic()):?>
     <?php echo '<img id="image" src="'.$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'organic')->keepAspectRatio(true)->keepFrame(false)->resize(950, null).'"/>';?>
<?php endif;?>
```

Hope this helps.

**Important**

`organic` is the name I gave to attribute, if you give something else, then need to change these too:

`getOrganic()` to `getYourname()` and
`$this->getProduct(), 'organic'` to `$this->getProduct(), 'yourname'`.